# can p = Process() be given outside if __name__ == '__main__' in python?

Tags: python, flask, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multi-processing in python to run some 10 functions parallelly.
But in every example I saw the spawning of a process done only inside if **name** = "**main**". I am using flask api in my python code so have to call app.run() and from there am calling main(). So my doubt is can I do that spawing of processes for multi-processing usage inside main() and not in if **name** ?

This is a minimal version of my code

```
app= Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
@app.route('/')
def index():
     return render_template('firstpage.html')
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def getvalue():
    #some basic declarations
    main()
    flask.jsonify({'html': filename})

def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    createDirectory("Myapp")
    p1 = Process(target=func1(mycol1,mycol2))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2(mycol3,mycol4))
    p2.start()
    p3 = Process(target=func3(mycol5,mycol6))
    p3.start()
    p4 = Process(target=func4(mycol7,mycol8))
    p4.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have 10 functions like this. Any suggestions on improving the code or the approach will be helpful.

Comment: yes you can call Process() anywhere

Comment: Do you want to invoke different processes or invoke separate functions parallelly? Both are different things. If you want to invoke functions parallelly, use threads, otherwise processes. 



PS:Be cautious about not calling the `app.run()` every time you spawn a process / thread.

Comment: Please create and post an [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: Thank you. Yes I tried. But there is no difference in the execution time. I mean the execution time was in fact more than the execution time for the code without multi-processing. It's weird. I can't figure out where am making a mistake.

Comment: Okay i'll add a minimal example

Comment: You might want to read about [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Comment: @AndrewScott I want to invoke separate functions parallelly. And yeah I tried it with threads.. No improvement in execution time. So I thought multi processing will achieve true parallelism. Can you please tell me where am wrong?

Comment: Your code which create four process for each request is generally not good practice for API server, because creating process is heavy task. There's some choice you can choose instead of creating process, but it depends on what you want to achieve. Therefore you should explain why you considered to use multiple process in your code. Maybe this question is [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Akila, can you post your full code somewhere like [ideone](https://ideone.com/)? I'd like to know what's causing the issue. Like ymonad said, this sounds like the XY problem

Comment: @AndrewScott As you mentioned GIL is the issue. I read about it and found how its affecting. And yeah at - ymonad ( Sorry I am allowed to use only one @ in a comment ) as you said the creating process approach is quite heavy for this. I did some more analysis and used async in python and its working perfectly now. Thank you everyone for your input. Learned a lot.